# Submitting large amount of form data to PHP using POST

Tags: php, html, mysql

We are designing a system for conducting a survey in which it askes user a about 72 questions (Multiple Choice questions)
And when the user submits this will be posted to php page which will save the answer in a MySQL table. 
Its works fine and perfectly well when we doing the test with a small number of user
But I observed the when a large amount of users are submitting not all data reaches the server only a part of some users answer (around 65 answer) only reaches the server.But i get data from my all users but some answers aren't compete.
Am using MySql engine : MyISAM 
What would be the problem or how can i solve this. is it the problem with some php configuration or mysql (large number of insert statement)
What is the best way to handle larger amount data from a form submission php
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limit on `POST` request size in PHP. You can adjust [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) in your `php.ini`. As for database, I don't know how you are saving them in the database, but there are character/storage limitation on the database as well.

Whenever I'm dealing with large `POST` data like sending numerous field values through forms, using ajax does wonders! Try using jQuery [`$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), which is the shorthand for [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). It's quite easy to use, even if you're not that familiar with jQuery :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to Increase max_input_vars from php.ini OR you can set the following code in your .htaccess file.

```
php_value max_input_vars 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ajax function for post the data..

Go through bellow link,it might help you

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp